# Fixed position shader background in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I'd like to have a pixel shader as a background in three.js I noticed that most just implement it as a 2d plane. But I'd still like to rotate my camera with [OrbitContols](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls) but not have it effect the position of the plane. In other words, I just want it as a fixed background in my scene.

Is there a way to make that plane fixed as just a 2d background (maybe layer two separate canvas three.js on top of eachother?), or some other way to make this work using three?

```
var planeMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { 
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent
} );

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, planeMaterial);
plane.position.z = -500;
scene.add(plane);
```

Here's an example of what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/5zTz3/2/

Comment: As an alternative to gman's answer, there is a library for it: https://github.com/llewelld/shaderback.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the shader material in a separate scene with a separate camera. then call `renderer.render(shadertoyScene, shadertoyCamera);` followed by `renderer.render(regularScene, orbitControlCamera);`.

```js
'use strict';

/* global THREE */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
  renderer.autoClear = false;

  const shadertoyCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    -1, // left
     1, // right
     1, // top
    -1, // bottom
    -1, // near,
     0, // far
  );
  const shadertoyScene = new THREE.Scene();
  const plane = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2, 2);

  const fragmentShader = `
  #include <common>

  uniform vec3 iResolution;
  uniform float iTime;

  // By iq: https://www.shadertoy.com/user/iq  
  // license: Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.
  void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
  {
      // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
      vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

      // Time varying pixel color
      vec3 col = 0.5 + 0.5*cos(iTime+uv.xyx*40.0+vec3(0,2,4));

      // Output to screen
      fragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
  }

  void main() {
    mainImage(gl_FragColor, gl_FragCoord.xy);
  }
  `;
  const uniforms = {
    iTime: { value: 0 },
    iResolution:  { value: new THREE.Vector3() },
  };
  const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    fragmentShader,
    uniforms,
  });
  shadertoyScene.add(new THREE.Mesh(plane, material));
  
  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 3;

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  function makeInstance(geometry, color, x) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color});

    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    cube.position.x = x;

    return cube;
  }

  const cubes = [
    makeInstance(geometry, 0x44aa88,  0),
    makeInstance(geometry, 0x8844aa, -2),
    makeInstance(geometry, 0xaa8844,  2),
  ]; 

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    uniforms.iResolution.value.set(canvas.width, canvas.height, 1);
    uniforms.iTime.value = time;

    renderer.render(shadertoyScene, shadertoyCamera);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```